# How to Configure KILE for ViewPDF settings?

Tags: kile

I have Kubuntu 16.04 installed and would like to configure it so that when I  do a **QUICKBUILD** okular will automatically open up and show the new pdf. This worked fine on Kubuntu 14.04, but ever since I upgraded, I have to open the pdf manually.  (so I open my file manager, find the correct folder, then click the pdf)

my configuration:  from **SETTINGS** menu, then **Configure Kile** dialog, then **Tools>Build>Quickbuild** Kile shows that *quickbuild* runs the following tool functions: **PDFLaTeX,ViewPDF**

The pdf gets generated correctly. Apparently the **ViewPDF** isn't popping open the pdf with Okular (or anything else) though.

So, I looked at the **ViewPDF** function to see what it's doing... according to the Configuration Dialog it's doing these two things, [1st]*ViewPDF command*: **okular**  [2nd]*ViewPDF options*: **'%target'**

My only ideas are that maybe it's not finding the target file, or maybe it's not finding okular, or maybe it's not even running the commands I'm seeing listed.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you choose `ViewPDF` manually from the menu rather than opening the PDF yourself? That will tell you more about where the problem is. Also, you can look in `~/.xsession-errors` in case there is some meaningful information there. (Look right after triggering the problem, though, as KDE simply spews stuff to this file all the time.)

Comment: *ViewPDF* does pop open the pdf file, not freshly generated though.  (But now that's simple enough to just pick one button, then the other) Here's some extra, I thought it was peculiar that under Kile's LOG AND MESSAGES, it second message line is **[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1** but it's actually just getting started.  The last message is **[PDFLaTeX] 0 errors, 6 warnings, 52 badboxes**  the log file is a full 60K.  This is a BOOK document.  j

Comment: Please test with a minimal document - a 'hello, world!' in LaTeX - to check whether the problem is specific to something about your document. If pdfLaTeX finishes with exit code 1, it doesn't keep going, so it is hard to make sense of what you're reporting. Presumably, these are from different compilations as the messages there can sometimes accumulate across runs.

Comment: **QuickBuild** worked on tiny Article, 6 total Kile messages 1>[PDFLaTeX] testLaTeX.tex... 2>[PDFLaTeX] 0 errors... 3>[PDFLaTeX]Done! 4>[ViewPDF] testLaTeX.pdf (okular) 5>[ViewPDF]Done!  THEN, I went back and ran my BOOK (scrbook class) but **QuickBuild**  didn't open the pdf.  INTERESTING:  when I press QuickBuild on the book, it pops up the first message instantly, 1>[PDFLaTeX] mybookName.tex... then it processes for about 10 seconds.  Then it spits out all the other many lines. There are no [PDFLaTeX]Done! or [ViewPDF]Done!  (2nd line still) [PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1

Comment: It is definitely a problem with your document rather than with Kile's configuration. You need to make a minimal example - either to find the problem yourself or to post here for help, if you can't figure it out. It is never safe to ignore compilation errors even if the resulting PDF looks OK.

Comment: That makes sense. The last Message is still: **[PDFLaTeX] 0 errors, 6 warnings, 52 badboxes**  and that's after it says: 
**[PDFLaTeX] finished with exit code 1,**  which was the second message (after it had paused for about 10 seconds, then spit out a long list of messages).  Last thing:  I deleted the .aux and .toc file associated with my book, and from the terminal ran **pdflatex myBook.tex**  The terminal halted 9 times with a **?**  (I hit [enter] each time) and then it finally completed.  And then I ran it again.  The book and contents look normal.  Is that pausing with a **?** normal?

Comment: No. That pausing with `?` is not normal. Unless your code has explicitly requested TeX to pause, it will only do this - as far as I know - if there's a compilation error. The console output will tell you why it is pausing. If you press `h` it will try to give you help. If it isn't really an error, it will tell you that, too!